# tar archive restarts after a certain time

Tags: centos, tar, archive

I have a folder with over 200k files in it. I want to archive only the ones beginning with a certain name(file names are super large). Example `sudo find /path/to/_Logs -name "RATE*" -print0 | xargs -0 tar -czf logs_rate.tgz`.

However, from time to time I receive the message : **tar:Removing leading `/' from member names** and the archive resets to 0 and starts over. At the end of the process I only have about 25 files out of a total of 22000. What am I missing or what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is `sudo find /path/to/_Logs -name "RATE*" -print0 | wc -c` larger than `getconf ARG_MAX`?

Comment: @LjmDullaart it doesn't matter. `xargs` will run the tar command multiple times even if it's less than `ARG_MAX` . It's a common misconception that `xargs` will use as many arguments as possible; it will use a much lower value. Use `xargs --show-limits` to show which one (it's usually 128k).

Comment: @Aiu That's because `xargs` does not run a single instance of `tar` will all the files, but will run in multiple times with batches of arguments.
Useless to say, this will keep recreate the archive, and in the end it will only contain the last batch of files.

You could try increasing the command line limit defaults of `xargs`, may it will be able to cope with all the files in a single run. E.g. with `xargs -0 -s 2093104`.

Comment: @user414777: the point is, as you correctly stated, that `xargs` runs tar multiple times. If the limit would be `getconf ARG_MAX`, on my system, with 200k files, that would leave about 10 chars per filename. So it would hit that limit as well.

Comment: @user414777 what does the -s 2093104 do? What do these numbers stand for?

Comment: @Aiu It increases the argument limit of `xargs` (max length of all the arguments and envvars, including their terminating NUL character). It's mentioned in the manpage -- read it. BTW, notice that `sudo` will only apply to the `find` command, `tar` will still run as the regular user and will FAIL to archives the files which is not able to read.

Comment: understood. That's not an issue since I'm in my own /home/ directory and the user has read access to the _Logs folder .

Comment: @AiureaAdicatotYO If the user has access, then why do `sudo` at all?

Answer (score 0):

As the comments already suggest, `tar` is run multiple times by `xargs`. The most obvious way to handle this would be to append the files to the archive instead of re-creating the archive from scratch.

```
 sudo find /path/to/_Logs -name "RATE*" -print0 | xargs -0 tar -rf logs_rate.tar
```

and compress afterwards.

The remark about the leading `/` is a warning only.

Comment: Commands like this are not recommended. There are better ways that are not based on side effects.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround. Split the command in 2 different things to bypass the long names and large content.

1. `sudo find /path/to/_Logs -name "RATE*" > test1.txt`
2. `tar -czvT test1.txt -f logs.tgz`

Comment: You seriously lost me with the "naming the program tar" . I used tar to create the archive as per my needs.

Comment: @Aiu better: `find ... -type f -print0 | tar --null -T- -zcf logs.tgz`. (assuming GNU `tar` and `find`, as you already do).

Answer (score 0):

Do not use xargs with tar. There is no need to do so.

Gnu/tar (and I believe other tars) have an option `-T` (long form: `--files-from`) to read an unlimited number of filenames from a side file. (You can also send them through stdin using `-T -`.)

The `--null` option can be used so that the `-T` list can contain null-terminated strings, just like `xargs` (and for the same reason).

Multiple `-T` options can be used. Note that pathnames starting with `-` are still a problem: the `-T` option is merely an abbreviation for a list of names on the command line: it can include other options, such as `-C`.

Comment: "and I believe other tars) have an option `-T`" No they don't. `bsdtar` (which is **not** the default tar on all BSDs) does have it, but `bsdtar` kind of strives for GNU tar compatibility.

Comment: I will hide behind the `Centos` tag on the question, then -- I did check the man page for that one. IIRC, my technique on SunOS 1.6 was to make a directory stuffed with symbolic links to all the files I wanted, and then use the tar -h option in that directory.